# How to set "set_charset('utf8');" for the entire class:

Tags: php, database, class, character-encoding

Hi I know how to set "set_charset('utf8');" with style:

```
$db = new mysqli('127.0.0.1','root','pass','data') or die ('error with connection');
$db->set_charset('utf8');
```

But now I want to do this with classes like:

```
class Core {
protected $db, $result;
private $rows;

public function __construct(){
    $this->db = new mysqli('127.0.0.1','root','pass','data');

    }

public function query ($sql){
    $this->result = $this->db->query($sql);
    }

public function rows(){
    for($x =1; $x<= $this->db->affected_rows; $x++){
        $this->rows[] = $this->result->fetch_assoc();
        }
        return $this->rows;
    }
}
```

But I cannot create this db set charset part, it's always some kind of error :)

Please help,
Thank you

Comment: And what kind of error is it exactly?

Comment: There is no error with the code posted, it works fine. The problem is when I try to insert the "set_charset('utf8');" part. If I try under the `$this->db = new mysqli('127.0.0.1','root','pass','data');` with: `$this->set_charset('utf8');` it gives me "Fatal error: Call to undefined method Homepage::set_charset()"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works fine, but in your comment i've found a bug.

Try this solution:

```
class Core extends mysqli
{
    protected $db, $result;
    private $rows;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct('127.0.0.1','root','pass','data');

        if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
            throw new exception('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '. mysqli_connect_error());
        }

        $this->set_charset('utf-8');
    }


    public function query($sql)
    {
        $this->result = parent::query($sql);
    }
}
```

When you call the Core class as Object, automatically the connection with database will be created and will be set the charset UTF-8.

The class MySQLI was extended to reuse all your methods like $core_class_object->stmt_init();